# Configuring time-to-live property at run time

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have to set the time-to-live property in jms:outbound gateway at run time based on the message input. Is that possible and if yes how?

Comment: May i know why do you want to set the time-to-live property at runtime?

Comment: we will have more number of messages being pushed to the queue and hence we need to prioritize the messages to reside in the queue, say for some messages it is enough if it is present in queue for 30 minutes while some may have around 2 hours. So is this possible??

Comment: Try using `Message.setJMSExpiration()` based on message's priority and have the time-to-live property to the maximum jms message expiry

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have one more doubt, all the configuration for the queue are done in the spring-integration.xml[<int-jms:outbound-gateway time-to-live = "4000"/>]. Hence when I put a message in the queue, how to override these properties.

Comment: AFAIK, You cannot override this property of the queue. instead set the expiration time of the message before you place it in the queue

Comment: thanks for the quick response. let me try

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is enough to use for this purpose an existing default `headerMapper`. And you have to place to the Spring Integration Message an appropriate header with name **JMSExpiration**

Comment: you and octopus conculded the same answer. right !! and thanks artem.